# Making HTTP Requests in Cocoa mimic browser

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, http, macos

So I am trying to read the contents of an HTML file to scrape some metadata off of a particular website.

The issue I am running into however is that performing the HTTP requests in objective-c using the cocoa library calls gives me a different HTML file then when I perform the call via a web browser or my implemented python call.

The reason why this is annoying, is that I am scraping a key that is generated on every request. The site seems to know when I performing the request via cocoa instead of from the python library or from the browser.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Here is the following python code I perform:

```
self.url = 'http://sample-site.com/1?ax=1ts=123123.12'
request = urllib2.Request(complete_url)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
html_data = response.read()
```

Here is the following cocoa attempts I've tried:

1. `NSString * completeUrl = [url stringByAppendingFormat:@"//%d?ax=1&ts=%1.2f", pageNumber, time];`
2. Another attempt:

   ```
       NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:hypeURL] autorelease];
       [request setValue:userAgent forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
       NSURLResponse* response = nil;
       NSError* error = nil;
       NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
       NSString *hypeHTML = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
   ```

The attempts in cocoa are retrieving the HTML however the HTML contains key values which I parse which are generated each refresh. When performing the requests using cocoa however the key values do not change upon each execution of the application (the same key is in the HTML) where in the Python, the HTML correctly has different keys for each request.

Thanks

Comment: Please check out this blog post I wrote describing the issue: http://www.fzakaria.com/2011/03/hypemachine-cocoa-woes/

Answer (score 3):

The website probably detects the user-agent and returns different content based on it.
Simply change the user-agent in the header of your request:

```
NSString* userAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.8) Gecko/20051111 Firefox/1.5 BAVM/1.0.0";
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.stackoverflow.com/"];
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease];
[request setValue:userAgent forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
NSURLResponse* response = nil;
NSError* error = nil;
NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",result);
```

With this code, the server thinks you're running Firefox on Linux :)

Get current user-agent / lookup user-agents for specific browsers:
http://www.useragentstring.com/

Comment: That doesn't seem to have done the trick... Is there any other way in which they could be figuring it out?

Comment: Besides some specific JavaScript / AJAX tricks, there is no other way for the server to detect the browser. The code above should work properly. Maybe the website is using AJAX to update the page? In that case, NSURLConnection returns of course something different then the 'view source' option in your browser.

Comment: They are using Ajax to update the page. What would the NSURLConnection retrieve then instead? Because it is still parsing the page appropriately ( i am regexing for specific identifiers in the source such as a id, key, etc..). I'll edit my original post with more comprehensive information

Comment: In that case: NSURLConnection is not going to work. NSURLConnection only downloads the plain text, it does not render or parse anything. Easy solution: Use WebView. After WebView rendered the page you can get the source code (including AJAX updates) from it. _(Note: If Python works, Cocoa should also work. Are you sure you translated the code correctly?) _

Comment: It is properly scraping the HTML. The reason why I know they are doing something wonky is that I am parsing a key from the HTML file. The key normally changes with every connection/page refresh. For instance in python the HTML it retrieves has a different key each time. However in cocoa the key in the HTML doesn't change...\